# Alternatives to RestKit or ASIHTTPRequest for iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios5, asihttprequest, restkit

Are there any alternatives for connecting to a web service with iOS, other than RestKit or ASIHTTPRequest?  ASIHTTPRequest is no longer being updated, so I'd like to know if there is anything currently being supported and updated other than RestKit.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for `ASIHTTPRequest` whatsoever. Everything you need can be accomplished with **NSURLConnection** and its delegate.

Comment: +1 for using the built-in robust capabilities of the frameworks.  I believe that AFNetworking offers a number of conveniences; and I use it sometimes.  But there are still edge cases around self-signed SSL certs that can be problematic.

Comment: @alanduncan ,I concur. I had experienced the same issues. I developed my own `HTTPSURLConnectionDelegate` adhering to <NSURLConnectionDelegate> protocol. Works like magic with my own certs.

Comment: I once used ASIHTTPRequest. I've moved to NSURLConnection+BlocksKit. It is working well in multiple projects. BlocksKit adds completion blocks which enable solutions that are more elegant than the standard delegate approach.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Spaghetti](https://github.com/noodlewerk/Spaghetti). It's a nice replacement for RestKit, especially if the web server that you connect to is not as RESTfull as you hoped. Happy support available.

Comment: nice, hows business in silicon valley ;) ?

Answer (score 2):

The author of ASI (long may it be missed!) recommends [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). Based on what I've seen here, it seems a popular choice.

You can of course roll your own with the built in NSURLConnection stuff that comes with the framework.

Answer (score 2):

Replacement for RestKit is
[SLazeKit](https://github.com/shial4/SLazeKit) framework providing models mapper and CoreData serializer for RESTful resources.

SLazeKit allows you to:

- map your models by Codable protocol
- serialize CoreData models from API responses
- fast and simple extend your models with API & CoreData

It is written in Swift. However, others of you my find it useful. :)